# How to convert Sting `8.1.009.125` to `double` array? java

Tags: java, arrays, string

How to convert Sting `8.1.009.125` to `double` array?

```
double[] arr = new double[4];
arr[0] = 8;
arr[1] = 1;
arr[2] = 0.09;
arr[3] = 125;
```

Not considered.String may be ulimited length, and may contains zeros at the begining.

```
  for (int i = 0; i <arr.length ; i++) {
        arr[i] = Double.valueOf(s1.replace(".", ""));
    }
```

result for arr filling: `[8.1009125E7, 8.1009125E7, 8.1009125E7, 8.1009125E7]`

I need to get `[8, 1, 0.09, 125]` from `String = "8.1.009.125"`

Main problem is String delimeted by dots.

And I need save value 0.09 from `String temp = "8.1.009.125"`

to get an Number array (float, double)  `[8, 1, 0.09, 125]`

How can I do this?

May be there is another way? Besides array?

Comment: 00.9? what is wrong with 0.09? that would make more sense

Comment: yes, mean 0.09, mistake sorry. I'll fix it.

Comment: next to that, who is to say 125 isn't supposed to be 1.25?

Comment: it's not contains zeros before 125, like `00125`, I have issue only with zeros.

Comment: Wouldn't "00125" be 0.0125? How would you represent 1.25 with you rules?

Comment: Delimited by 4 dots allways 1.25 means first cell 1, second 25. Represent it like `IP address`

Comment: Sure, but if you want to represent real number with your notation, like 0.09 (reprsented by 009), you could want to represent the number 1.25.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some workaround for your specific case. 
If you have string with zero at the begining `009` you can create a new one with right format `0.09` and then convert to double value as `Double.valueOf(string)`

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "8.1.009.125";
    String[] strings = s.split("\\.");
    for (String string : strings) {
        if (string.startsWith("0")) {
            string = "0." + string.substring(1);
        }
        System.out.println(Double.valueOf(string));
    }

}
```

Comment: Still rule must be well defined and properly implemented... 009 -> 9, 0.9, 0.09, 0.009 which one is correct? if it will be 000009 then what?

Comment: will be `9.0E-5`, BUT PROBLEM IS SOLVED.

Answer (score 3):

That's of course untested code...

```
public Double[] convertTab(String myStr) {
  //We start by splitting the string:
  String[] tab = myStr.split("\\.");

  //We need a structure of double as a result
  List<Double> result = new ArrayList<Double>();

  //Then we loop on the different elements of the table
  for (String sNum : tab) {
    //Then we convert, which isn't easy because the rules are ambiguous in your question
    result.add(convertDouble(sNum);
  }

  return result.toArray();
}

public double convertDouble(String sDouble) {
  int accu = 1;
  for (int i=0;i<sDouble.length();i++) {
    //We count the number of 0
    if (sDouble.charAt(i) == '0') {
      accu = accu*10;
    } else {
      //Parsing of the remaining digits and division
      return Double.parseDouble(sDouble)/accu;
    }
}
```

Comment: yw. BTW result can be directly array as long as after string splitted there is a needed size available. but... actually I love List and hate arrays in Java :-)

Comment: Interested only values with zeros at the begining. `String s = "009.001.01.003"` How to converted it in double  [0.09, 0.01, 0.1, 0.03]. Problem with dots

Answer (score 0):

First you `split` your `String`, create a `double` array with the same size and copy the elements, modifying them where necessary.:

```
String inputArray[] = input.split("\\.");

double outputArray = new double[input.length];

for (int index = 0; index < inputArray.length; index++) {
    if ((inputArray[index].length() > 1) && (inputArray[index].startsWith("0"))) inputArray = inputArray.substring(0, 1) + "." + inputArray.substring(1);
    outputArray[index] = Double.valueOf(inputArray[index]);
}
```